# Get new solution directly after changing constraint weight

Tags: optaplanner

I am dynamically changing constraint weights with @ConstraintConfiguration and @ConstraintWeight. How to force the Solver to react immediately to constraint weight changes?

To achieve that I currently add new problem change, where I make an empty change.

```
changeConstraintWeights(weights)

allJobData[jobId]?.solverJob?.addProblemChange(
            EmptyChange()
        )
```

EmptyChange looks like this:

```
public class EmptyChange implements ProblemChange<MySolution> {
    public EmptyChange() {}
    @Override
    public void doChange(
        MySolution solution,
        ProblemChangeDirector problemChangeDirector
    ) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@ConstraintConfiguration` annotation is typically applied on a field/getter in your solution. The object that is accessed by that field/getter becomes a fact in the solver's working memory. Therefore the only thing you need to do is to send a problem change that changes that object.

However, because any problem change resets the solver's working solution and that causes the reload of constraint configuration anyway, sending your dummy problem change has the exact same effect.